# What is the Alternative for FarPoint text box Change Event in Dot Net text box

Tags: vb.net

I have replaced text box of Far Point Input Pro Edit control with dot net native text box control.

There was an event called "Change" in Far point box which I am not able to see in Dot Net text box.. Does anyone know what is the replacement for the "Change" event?

Below is the Far Point change event signature.

```
 Private Sub FarPoint_Change(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles FarPoint.Change
end Sub
```

Comment: Maybe TextChanged ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Sorry for being dumb. I overlooked this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event might be what you are looking for.